# How do I create a user-defined aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, aggregate, functions

I need an aggregate function that MySQL doesn't provide.

I would like it to be in MySQL's flavor of SQL (that is, not in C).

How do I do this?  What I'm stuck on is creating an aggregate function -- the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html) don't seem to mention how this is done.

Examples of desired usage of a `product` function:

```
mysql> select product(col) as a from `table`;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|  144 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select col, product(col) as a from `table` group by col;
+-----+------+
| col | a    |
+-----+------+
|   6 |   36 |
|   4 |    4 |
+-----+------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-udf.html it's only possible to write aggregate functions in C. Sorry!

Comment: Either C or C++. Not SQL, anyway.

Comment: I presume any language which can generate binary libraries in the platform-supported binary format with C calling conventions.

Comment: I don't know. It was *documented* as "C or C++ (or another language that can use C calling conventions)" in version 5.0. The docs dropped "or another language that can use C calling conventions" in version 5.1.  That's a strange phrase to drop.

Comment: is it available in recent mysql versions now (after few years) ?

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if there is way to define a new aggregate function, not without messing with MySQL source code.

But if your numbers are all positive, you may well derive from the arithmetic identity:

```
log( product( Ai ) ) = sum( log( Ai ) )
```

that you can use `EXP(SUM(LOG(x)))` to calculate `PRODUCT(x)`. Test in [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbd54/9):

```
SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(a))) AS product
FROM t ;

SELECT col, EXP(SUM(LOG(a))) AS product
FROM t 
GROUP BY col ;
```

---

When the data can have 0s, it gets a bit more complicated:

```
SELECT (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE a = 0)) 
       * EXP(SUM(LOG(a))) AS p
FROM t 
WHERE a > 0 ;

SELECT d.col, 
       (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t AS ti WHERE ti.col = d.col AND ti.a = 0)) 
       * COALESCE(EXP(SUM(LOG(t.a))),1)  AS p
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT col
      FROM t
    ) AS d
  LEFT JOIN
    t  ON  t.col = d.col
       AND t.a > 0
GROUP BY d.col ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbd54/9)**

---

For other DBMS, that do not have MySQL's auto-conversion of boolean values to integers, the

```
(NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...))
```

should be replaced with:

```
(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1...) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```

Specifically for Oracle, a few more changes will be needed, without changing the logic of the answer, only because Oracle does not follow strict ANSI standard in some areas. Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f11a/29)**

Comment: That's sweet. High school math has come back to haunt me. +1 !!!

Comment: Cool math, but I actually wanted to know how to create an aggregate function in general.  `product` was just supposed to be one example of several.

Comment: This is pretty cool, but doesn't work if any of the values are zero, since log(0) is undefined.

Comment: @jameshfisher Correct. One can write easily the extra condition, checking for zeros (where the product would be zero of course). I didn't think at the time it was necessary to add that complication.

Comment: It's not clear to me how best to add that condition. We can't add the condition in the inner function of the values: since we want that `PRODUCT(..., 0, ...) = 0`, we want that `EXP(SUM(..., f(0), ...)) = 0`, for some `f` that we choose, but to satisfy this, we need that `SUM(..., f(0), ...) = LOG(0)` -- again thwarted by the same issue that log(0) is undefined. We need to check for the presence of zero in some other way, e.g. `MIN(ABS(a)) = 0`. So we'd have `SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(ABS(a)) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE EXP(SUM(LOG(a))) END AS product`. Is this the kind of thing you were thinking of?

Comment: @jameshfisher I edited the answer. It will surely get even more complicated with negative values.

Comment: @ypercube indeed. I suppose the approach would be to use the above approach on the `ABS` of the values, and negate it if there is an odd number of negative numbers in the list.

Comment: @jameshfisher Yes, right.

Answer (score 5):

In the interests of learning how to fish, I have successfully compiled and installed a "Hello, World!" UDF (user-defined function) for MySQL [found here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4l-jNhGAHYXYkZtcEV3eGJlMlU&usp=sharing). The hello_world.so file (after being complied with `gcc -shared -o hello_world.so -I /usr/include/mysql hello_world.c`) should be stored in /usr/lib/mysql/plugins/ with 755 permissions on Ubuntu linux systems. [The "-I /usr/include/mysql" is the path to the mysql header files; I found my code wouldn't compile without this parameter, but YMMV.]

The program does nothing but print out the string "Hello, World!" for each record in the resulting dataset of a query, but that's all it is supposed to do. I will try to write a SMALL aggregate function in the next few days. There is an example of an aggregate function which computes the average cost of a group of price and quantity records; the SMALL function shouldn't be that different from that function in the end.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Technically not a user defined aggregate function, and not optimal, but this works and doesn't need to create an UDF: use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in your query which will make your query an aggregate one and will consolidate all values in one comma-separated string, and then write a SQL function that processes that string.

Example (function based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213789/split-a-string-and-loop-through-values-in-mysql-procedure) answer)::

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `replace_multiple`(_text text, _from text, _to text) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE _nextfrom TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE _nextto TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE _nextlenfrom INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE _nextlento INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE _valuefrom TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE _valueto TEXT DEFAULT NULL;

iterator:
LOOP
  -- exit the loop if the list seems empty or was null;
  -- this extra caution is necessary to avoid an endless loop in the proc.
  IF CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(_from)) = 0 OR _from IS NULL THEN
    LEAVE iterator;
  END IF;

  -- capture the next value from the list
  SET _nextfrom = SUBSTRING_INDEX(_from,',',1);
  SET _nextto = SUBSTRING_INDEX(_to,',',1);

  -- save the length of the captured value; we will need to remove this
  -- many characters + 1 from the beginning of the string
  -- before the next iteration
  SET _nextlenfrom = CHAR_LENGTH(_nextfrom);
  SET _nextlento = CHAR_LENGTH(_nextto);

  -- trim the value of leading and trailing spaces, in case of sloppy CSV strings
  SET _valuefrom = TRIM(_nextfrom);
  SET _valueto = TRIM(_nextto);

  -- use the extracted value
  SET _text = replace(_text, _valuefrom, _valueto);

  -- rewrite the original string using the `INSERT()` string function,
  -- args are original string, start position, how many characters to remove,
  -- and what to "insert" in their place (in this case, we "insert"
  -- an empty string, which removes _nextlen + 1 characters)
  SET _from = INSERT(_from,1,_nextlenfrom + 1,'');
  SET _to = INSERT(_to,1,_nextlento + 1,'');
END LOOP;

RETURN _text;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Table t:

| id | fromThis | toThat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | one |
| 2 | 2 | two |
| 3 | 3 | three |

Query:

```
SELECT replace_multiple('my 2 cents', GROUP_CONCAT(fromThis), GROUP_CONCAT(toThat))
FROM t;
```

Will translate to:

```
SELECT replace_multiple('my 2 cents', '1,2,3', 'one,two,three')
```

Which for this specific custom function will return `my two cents`