# Oracle custom aggregate

Tags: oracle, aggregate

```
Year    Value
2012     10
2013     20
2014      0
```

I need `10 * 20 * 0` for multiple rows.
If I use this function  `EXP (SUM (LN (Value)))`, I get an ORA-01428  error:

> argument '0' is out of range.

I have seen [How do I create a user-defined aggregate function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17267/1192) but that is for MySQL, not Oracle and my requirement is to include zeroes.

Comment: The answer has a 2nd part, where it deals with 0s.

Comment: @ypercube: the proposed extension still does not work in Oracle. This question is in more than one respect not a duplicate at all. 1) Oracle allows user-defined aggregate-funcitons. 2) Your linked solution does not work in Oracle. To shed some light on the question why Oracle does not behave as expected, I posted a question on this site: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78805/ora-00937-when-calculating-a-sub-value-in-an-aggregate-select-statement

Comment: Yes, Oracle has a few quirks. The solution is valid, with only minor modifications. I agree thought that your solution, which creates a new aggregate function is good. (My link, corrected:) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f11a/29

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you can have your own aggregation function. To write one, we need to implement an interface which looks like this:

```
create /*or replace*/ type mult_agg_type as object (
    totalAggValue    number,
    static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT mult_agg_type) return number,
    member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT mult_agg_type, value IN number) return number,
    member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN mult_agg_type, returnValue OUT number, flags IN number) return number,
    member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT mult_agg_type, ctx2 IN mult_agg_type) return number
);
```

The above is just the type definition introducing the type with the required type interface amended by a field definition which stores the value aggregated so far.

This interface can be implemented as follows:

```
create /*or replace*/ type body mult_agg_type is

    static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT mult_agg_type) return number is
    begin
        sctx := mult_agg_type (null);
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

    member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT mult_agg_type, value IN number) return number is
    begin
        if self.totalAggValue is null then
            self.totalAggValue := value;
        else
            self.totalAggValue := self.totalAggValue*value;
        end if;
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

    member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN mult_agg_type, returnValue OUT number, flags IN number) return number is
    begin
        returnValue := self.totalAggValue;
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

    member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT mult_agg_type, ctx2 IN mult_agg_type) return number is
    begin
        self.totalAggValue := self.totalAggValue*ctx2.totalAggValue;
        return ODCIConst.Success;
    end;

end;
```

Now that the datatype is defined completely, we need to generate a stub function which can be used as an aggregating function in a select-statement:

```
create /*or replace*/ function agg_product(input number) RETURN number
    PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE using mult_agg_type;
```

I chose the name `agg_product`, but feel free to choose any name you prefer or like best. As an example of how this can be used in your case, try:

```
select agg_product(value) as prod from your_table_name;
```