# Product of an entire Collumn MySQL

Tags: mysql

Does MySQL have any functions like `SUM` but then do the `MULTIPLICATION` of a collumn?

**Example:**
I have an table like this, and I want to multiply the entire collumn

```
+--------------+
| combinations |
+--------------+
|            3 |
|            5 |
|            4 |
|            6 |
|            1 |
|            3 |
|            4 |
+--------------+
```

**expected** result:

```
+----------------------------+
| product_total_combinations |
+----------------------------+
|                       4320 |
+----------------------------+
```

I cannnot find anywhere how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained by [How do I create a user-defined aggregate function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17267/how-do-i-create-a-user-defined-aggregate-function) there is no such aggregate function (also see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)).

However you can emulate your product by:

```
log(product(x) ) = sum(log(x))

SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(a))) AS product
FROM t ;
```

Beware, there could be rounding errors. If this is all integers, do `ROUND(...)` around the `EXP`.

Comment: Yup this worked, thank you. I searched all morning but couldn't find any questions similar to mine.

Comment: Beware, there could be rounding errors.  If this is all integers, do `ROUND(...)` around the `EXP`.