# How do I create a user-defined aggregate function? (Part 2)

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I'm refering to this question:

[How do I create a user-defined aggregate function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17267/how-do-i-create-a-user-defined-aggregate-function)

My table contains Zero-Values so I have tried the example of ypercubeᵀᴹ but I got the message that

```
(NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM testmult WHERE wert = 0))
```

is a boolean and it can't be muliplied with

```
EXP(SUM(LOG(wert)))
```

> (**Error: "boolean * double precision"**)

So how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `MIN()` instead of trying to invent `PROD()`.  That way, any `0` will lead to a zero result (assuming all the values are non-negative).